# simple way convert python string to quoted string

Tags: python

i'm new to python and i'm having a select statement like following `help_category_id, name`, what is the most effective way to convert this string to this:

```
'help_category_id', 'name'
```

i've currently done this, which works fine, but is there a nicer and more clean way to do the same:

```
test_string = 'help_category_id, name'
column_sort_list = []
if test_string is not None:
    for col in test_string.split(','):
        column = "'{column}'".format(column=col)
        column_sort_list.append(column)
column_sort = ','.join(column_sort_list)
print(column_sort)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple one liner using looping constructs:

```
result = ", ".join(["'" + i + "'" for i.strip() in myString.split(",")])
```

What we are doing here is we are creating a list that contains all substrings of your original string, with the quotes added. Then, using `join`, we make that list into a comma delimited string.

Deconstructed, the looping construct looks like this:

```
resultList = []
for i in myString.split(","):
    resultList.append("'" + i.strip() + "'")
```

Note the call to `i.strip()`, which removes extraneous spaces around each substring.

**Note:** You can use format syntax to make this code even cleaner:

**New syntax:**

```
result = ", ".join(["'{}'".format(i.strip()) for i in myString.split(",")])
```

**Old syntax:**

```
result = ", ".join(["'%s'" % i.strip() for i in myString.split(",")])
```

Comment: okay the string can either be seperated by ``,`` or with a space ``, `` how can i be sure both is catched

Comment: @PeterPik Do you mean it can be separated only by spaces, or a comma and a space? If it is the latter, then my code already accounts for that.

Comment: it can be seperated by both comma and spaces and just comma just like in a sql statement

Comment: @PeterPik The code works for both comma only and comma and space (even mixed together in the same string).

Comment: oh just thought ``", ".join``only joined with comma and space

Answer (score 0):

it can be achieved by this also.

```
','.join("'{}'".format(value) for value in map(lambda text: text.strip(), test_string.split(",")))
```